# ASP.NET web application can't find an assembly

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, assembly

I deployed an ASP.NET web application last night and I when I woke up this morning it was very slow and would occasionally just throw a 'Service Unavailable' error.

I checked the Event Viewer and it was filled up with these errors:

[image]

I'm puzzled as it was working perfectly when I deployed it (MonoTorrent is required to retrieve the number of seeders/leechers for a certain torrent off the tracker - this was working fine), but it's no longer working and whenever code that uses MonoTorrent gets involved, the worker process just crashes.

MonoTorrent.dll is in the /bin/ directory.

Comment: Does it crash on the development box as well when you use MonoTorrent? Can you try putting this application in a new Application Pool and see if that works?

Comment: It's already in it's own Application Pool, and no it works perfectly on my dev box.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing monotorrent to the global assembly cache.

Comment: It doesn't have a strong name, so I can't do that.